# Error on importing Unity WebGl build in ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

I'm trying to load Unity game on web but this is the error I get on the console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at 8490a1a1-bf79-475c-a429-4588078be1fb:1:1)

react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Unable to parse /ddd.framework.js! The file is corrupt, or compression was misconfigured? (check Content-Encoding HTTP Response Header on web server)
```

My build file is in the client directory and index.html inside public directory:

```
import React from "react";
import { Unity, useUnityContext } from "react-unity-webgl";

function App() {
  const { unityProvider } = useUnityContext({
    loaderUrl: "build/ddd.loader.js",
    dataUrl: "build/ddd.data",
    frameworkUrl: "build/ddd.framework.js",
    codeUrl: "build/ddd.wasm",
  });

  return <Unity unityProvider={unityProvider} />;
}
```

Comment: And how do you combine it with React?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-unity-webgl I followed this documentation.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Is there something to do with my file structure? Because there is a post on GitHub which suggests the same, but I can't completely understand it. Here's the link: https://github.com/jeffreylanters/react-unity-webgl/issues/57

Comment: Toy didn't include any code, how can I know what's wrong?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I've edited the question for you

Comment: I'm pretty sure that these files have to be accessible through the browser. I guess moving them to the `public` would help, because you are probably using `create-react-app`